.Net MAUI: How to make page with customizable footer?
I need to make a type of page that has a footer with a button which simply closes (pops) the current page. I have implemented the footer in one page already, which looks like this:
<ContentPage ...>
  <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="0">
    ...
    </ScrollView>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonConfirm}" Margin="8,4" Text="Close" Clicked="ButtonExit_Clicked"/>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>

However, I do not think that manually implementing that on each page would be the wisest course of action since, if I have to change anything in the footer, I'll have to do so in every single page that has such footer, therefore I need a solution that allows me to create it once and then reuse it. After some research, I've figured that using an application-wide ControlTemplate would be the way to go. However, there are a few additional things that are required:

I must be able to hide the footer in some pages when I'm loading the content. Once loading is complete, I hide the loading VerticalStackLayout and then I'll show the page itself with the footer and its content;

As an example, I'll show what I currently do with said page:
<ContentPage ...>
  <StackLayout>
    <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="LayoutLoading" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
      <Label Text="Loading data. Please wait."/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="LayoutMain" IsVisible="False">
      <!--This is there the content with the footer would be-->
    </VerticalStackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

PS.: I do not know if that's the most appropriate way to implement a "loading" UI so I'm open to any suggestions in that regard as well.

I must be able to customize the button's OnClicked event and the Style and Text properties. Note that they still should have their original values if not overridden.

Even though I know you can set the ControlTemplate's data through TemplateBinding, that will not allow me to set a default value to these properties, will it? If so, how can I do that?
Therefore, as of now, I'm at a loss as to how I could implement all of this through a ControlTemplate. If possible, how can I do all of this?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: As fairly requested, here's what I've done so far:
In the App.xaml file:
<Application ...>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        ...
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

      <ControlTemplate x:Key="ContentFooter">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
          <ScrollView Grid.Row="0">
            <ContentPresenter/>
          </ScrollView>
          <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="8,4" Text="Close" Clicked="FooterButton_Clicked"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>


Note that I deliberately did not set bindings yet since the default values serve me well, even though I'll have to set them sometime soon.

Then, in the Page.xaml file:
<ContentPage ...
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ContentFooter}">

  <StackLayout>
    <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="LayoutLoading" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
      <Label Text="Loading data. Please wait."/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="LayoutMain" IsVisible="False">
      ...
    </VerticalStackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

As of now, the footer does work but I cannot hide it when the data is loading. Any suggestions as to how to do it will be appreciated.

Please focus your question on one issue at a time. Have you tried something yet with ControlTemplate ?

@Cfun Yes, I have implemented it in one of my pages but I don't know how to toggle its visibility nor how to set a default value to its bindings. Any suggestions on how to do so?

it would be more efficient if you share what have you done or achieve so far and we will go from there or a [mre]

@Cfun fair enough, I'll edit my post with what I've done

This (from Xamarin Forms) might be helpful for conditional rendering: https://xamgirl.com/stop-doing-isvisibletrue-false-to-show-hide-views-in-runtime-in-xamarin-forms/

Also see various suggestions on conditional rendering (including a video link I posted there) at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/11102
